# NPM how to deal with dist-tags like @beta, @next when the official new version is released?

Tags: node.js, npm

Let's say I have a npm package which `@latest` is on v2.3.0, and has a dist-tag `@next` that points to an alpha version `v3.0.0.alpha`. When `v3.0.0` is officially released, should I always keep `@next` tag to the latest version and run `npm dist-tag add mypkg@{latest} next` on every version release? Or if there's a more idiomatic way to manage the `@next` tag?

Comment: If there is no next development why not delete the next tab until you begin development on the next version?

Comment: @morganney I deleted that, but user are saying "npm install pkg@next" is broken, that made me second guess. I guess I should just tell them use `@latest` instead?